# I have a US A-2 visa. Can I go to the Canadian side of Niagara Falls?

Tags: visas, canada, niagara-falls

I am travelling in the United States on an A-2 visa ([foreign government officials and employees](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/other/diplomat-foreign-government-official.html)). I want to see Niagara Falls, but heard that the view from the Canadian side is better. Can I go to Canada to see the falls and stay there for the night?

Comment: I don't think it matters, but what is your citizenship? I don't think having an A-2 visa will allow you to enter Canada.

Comment: How long is your assignment to the US? If you will be there for a while, you may wish to apply for a Canadian visa. Note that a Canadian tourist visa is called a "temporary resident visa". The circumstances of a typical A-2 visa holder are such that it should be easy to obtain the visa.

Answer (score 4):

A temporary visa for the US does not imply any sort of right to enter Canada. Canada, being a separate country, has its own visa policies.

If citizens of your country would normally need a visa to enter Canada as a tourist, then you would also need a visa. A visit to Niagara Falls would not count as any kind of official government business.

Comment: Thank You Sir...Is it possible to visit Niagra falls while still remaining on to US side...I will be going from New York to NF just for sight seeing..so is it worth?

Comment: @saurabhlohani It is possible.  Is it worth it?  Your guess is as good as anyone elses.

Comment: @saurabhlohani Yes, you can remain on the US side.

Comment: You will want to take care when driving in that area because it is very easy to miss an exit and end up at the border. If you drive up to the border you are required to cross through and if you do not have the proper documentation it can be a big hassle.

Comment: @pnuts: As a counterpoint, [this view](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/Niagara+Falls,+NY,+USA/@43.0886744,-79.0642747,145m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x89d363ea29e633b7:0x61975ae4b9c5aab3!6m1!1e1?hl=en) shows a clear "escape hatch" for westbound vehicles that might accidentally find themselves at the start of the Rainbow Bridge to Canada.

Comment: @pnuts - the border crossings are all on bridges and while I guess Rainbow may have an "escape hatch" I have a friend who missed the "last exit before border" on his way to Niagara Falls from Binghamton, NY and was not permitted to avoid it. Maybe he also missed the "escape hatch"? But he did ask and was not permitted to turn back. He actually managed to have this happen twice -- he missed the exit on the way there then also got on the highway in the wrong direction going home. He was allowed back into the US both times but he gets a lot of hassles at immigration now every time he travels.

Comment: The Canadian view of the falls is better.